# Moving files in matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, filestream

I am working on a project in which i am asked to create 500 random numbers in c++ and store them in text file through file handling and open that specific file in MAT LAB for further processing.
As i write the file in c++,it is created in the project directory of my c++ compiler while to open that file in MAT LAB i need that file to be placed in the MAT LAB's directory,how can i move it over there? or is there any other command which i don't know in MAT LAB which used to open file from other directory?

P.S( I don't want to copy or move that file manually ,but to move it through or command aor open it directly )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have any problem reading the file using MATLAB's [fopen](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) by adding the path of your file before the filename.

However, if you really want to move a file in MATLAB, just use [movefile](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movefile.html). It will work, but there is no reason it would be any easier, and it would be a bit slower.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to not move them at all. Either use the full path when opening as @SylvainLobry suggested or add the directory to matlab's path using [addpath](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html) or the UI. You should then be able to open the files without giving the full path.